# jQuery get json_encode variable from PHP

Tags: php, jquery

My PHP file retrieves data from a PostgreSQL DB. I have to send them back to my jQuery function in two different arrays. One is passed by using:

```
echo json_encode($tb);
```

and works fine, in my js file i get data correctly by using:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './DB/lb.php',
    data: {d_p: oa},
    success: function (tb) {
      console.log(tb);
})
```

console output is as expected.

The other is always a PHP array, but I have to replace chars:

```
str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($ltb), ENT_NOQUOTES));
```

but if I write:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './DB/lb.php',
    data: {d_p: oa},
    success: function (tb, ltb) {
      console.log(tb);
      console.log(ltb);
})
```

**console.log(ltb)** simply outputs

> success

what I'm I getting wrong?

Comment: You can only return a single response in an AJAX request. I'm very confused about what you're trying to do though - why do you need that same data returned twice? If you need to amend the format of the returned data, do it client side from the object provided to your `success` handler

Comment: why u want to print array and not just json string as it works fine as u say

Comment: You must add this to $response["tb"] = $tb; $response["ltb"] = $ltb; echo json_encode($response); and in success just success: function (response){console.log(response.tb);console.log(response.ltb)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `succes` is the response staus. This is the reason because you get `success` when logging `tlb`.

You can only return one JSON at at time, so combine them:

```
echo json_encode(array("other stuff", "tb" => $tb, "tbl" => array("some" => "data")));
```

On JS side you can simple acces them by index or key:

```
tb[0];  // "other stuff"
tb.tb;  // content of $tb variable
tb.tbl; // {some: "data"}
```

Comment: `tl` stands for what? Is not referenced anywhere

Comment: Sorry, I have used `tl` instead of your `tb`. Fixed. @MorRob

Comment: `echo json_encode(array( "tb" => $tb, "ltb" => array(str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars($ltb, ENT_NOQUOTES)))));` returns now  **undefined**

Comment: Why not just `echo json_encode(array("tb" => $tb, "ltb" => $tlb));`?

Comment: `console.log(tb);` works fine, but `console.log(ltb);` returns **Uncaught ReferenceError: ltb is not defined**

Comment: I think you have to learn how objects and arrays work. ;) Try something like this: `success: function(response) { console.log(response.tb); console.log(response.tbl); }` @MorRob

Comment: perfectly right, I'm learning, especially with your support, but in any case I get **undefined**

Comment: Ah, maybe i got a typo in the php array. I wrote `ltb` instead of `tbl`. Can you check this in your php code please? @MorRob

Comment: I had already noticed and fixed, it's not that case. If  `success: function(response) { console.log(response.tb); console.log(response.ltb); }`  both become **undefined**

Comment: I have to see your code then again with your current state. JS and PHP. There is a problem somewhere ...

Comment: Yes it could, but in any case you answered my question, I'll go deeper in my code to understand why. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The final working code:

**PHP:**

```
$tb = array();
$ltb = array();
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
    {
      array_push($ltb, $row["x"], $row["y"]); 
      array_push($tb, $row["z"],$row["t"]);
    } 

    echo json_encode(array('tb'=>$tb,'ltb'=>$ltb));
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './DB/lb.php',
    dataType: 'json', // this is what I forgot!!!
    data: {d_p: oa}, // passes variable for PHP function
success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.tb+" "+ response.ltb);
$.each(response.tb, function( i, item ) {
  // iterate over tb array
}
$.each(response.ltb, function( i, item ) {
  // iterate over ltb array
}
});
```